# What to do next after retrieving Facebook authentication token?

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, facebook-authentication

Framework: React Native
React Native V: 0.66.2
Backend: NodeJs
Facebook Lib: [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next)

I am developing a React Native application. There I have implemented authentication via Facebook. Everything works fine and I am successfully getting the token, however I don't know what to do with it :)

How should I check for it's validity on NodeJs backend **OR** Are there any SDK/libs such as *jsonwebtoken* **OR** how am I supposed to deal with it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firebase, after getting the token, you can use `@react-native-firebase/auth` and then using the `auth()` function from `@react-native-firebase` to get the data of the user

```
const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
const dataAuth = await auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
```

variable `dataAuth` will return information of the user